# calculating Tree ring and monthly precipitation in R

Tags: r

I'm new to the area of dendrology and R programming. I have tree ring data stretching from 1884 to 2019 and monthly precipitation data from 1950 to 2019. I want to calculate the correlation between tree growth and monthly precipitation from 1950 to 2019. I also want to do the correlation between growth at year 1 monthly meteorological variables during that year (Jan-Oct) and also with meteorological variables the year before. The issue is I don't know how to create a code that I can use to compute any of the above, can someone please help.

This is what I have managed to do at the moment:

```
 rm(list = ls())

# load in dplR package
library(dplR)

# AF28OFINAL
# read in measurements
chaf28o6 <- read.rwl("F:/chaf28o6.rwl")
library(readr)
#
rwl.report(chaf28o6)
#
plot(chaf28o6, plot.type="spag")
# detrending all the series in the chaf2806 at once
chaf28o6.rwl <- detrend(rwl = chaf28o6, method = "Friedman")

#descriptive statistics
rwl.stats(chaf28o6[1:17])
#Building a Mean Value Chronology
chaf28o6.crn <- chron(chaf28o6.rwl, prefix = "CAM")
##
library(treeclim)
Abies2800 <- chaf28o6.crn
library(readr)


 clim2800 <- read_csv("Prec.csv", col_types = cols(Year = col_number(), 
                                                  Month = col_number(), Tp = col_number()))
View(clim2800)

## correlation function analysis## when I try to run the following code, I get the error message: Error in x[1, 1]:x[dim(x)[1], 1] : NA/NaN argument
dcc(chrono = Abies2800,
    climate = clim2800,
    selection = 1:10,
    method = "cor",
    dynamic = "static",
    win_size = 25,
    win_offset = 1,
    start_last = TRUE,
    timespan = NULL,
    var_names = NULL,
    ci = 0.05,
    boot = "stationary",
    sb = TRUE
    )
```

Comment: You will need to provide some reproducible data first and show us what you have tried so far. If your precipitation data is monthly and your tree ring data is annual, you will have to combine 12 months into annual precipitation before you can correlate ring thickness and precipitation.

Comment: This is not reproducible data. Put your code in your original question, not a comment. How is this code not producing what you want?

Comment: The issue is, I'm new to this platform, I'm new to R, and I'm also new to dendrochronology. so, I'm still trying to find my way through all these platforms. Is it okay if I post the datafiles here maybe you can take a look at them?

Comment: Illustrate your efforts using the `muc_spruce` and `muc_clim` that come with the package `treeclim` that you are using. Have you worked through the example on the manual page for `dcc`? When I try to load `bootRes`, I get the following error "Package ‘bootRes’ was removed from the CRAN repository."